# Flutter MultiProvider Consumer trigger - How to prevent multi rebuilds?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
repo = Provider.of<ProductSessionRepository>(context);
shopInfoRepository = Provider.of<ShopInfoRepository>(context);
psValueHolder = Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context, listen: false);

final Widget _expansionTileTitleWidget = Text(
    Utils.getString(context, 'detail_info_tile__session_info'),
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1);

return MultiProvider(
    providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
      ChangeNotifierProvider<RegisteredProductSessionProvider>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (BuildContext context) {
            final RegisteredProductSessionProvider provider =
                RegisteredProductSessionProvider(
                    repo: repo, userId: psValueHolder.loginUserId);
            if (widget.isNavRegistered) {
              provider.getRegisteredProductSessionList(widget.productId);
            }
            return provider;
          }),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<EnrolledProductSessionProvider>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (BuildContext context) {
            final EnrolledProductSessionProvider provider =
                EnrolledProductSessionProvider(
                    repo: repo, userId: psValueHolder.loginUserId);
            if (!widget.isNavRegistered) {
              provider.getEnrolledProductSessionList(widget.productId);
            }
            return provider;
          }),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductSessionProvider>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (BuildContext context) {
            final ProductSessionProvider provider = ProductSessionProvider(
                repo: repo, userId: psValueHolder.loginUserId);
            productSessionProvider = provider;
            return provider;
          }),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ShopInfoProvider>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (BuildContext context) {
            final ShopInfoProvider provider = ShopInfoProvider(
                repo: shopInfoRepository,
                psValueHolder: psValueHolder,
                ownerCode: 'HomeDashboardViewWidget');
            provider.loadShopInfo();
            return provider;
          }),
    ],
    child: Consumer3<ShopInfoProvider, EnrolledProductSessionProvider,
            RegisteredProductSessionProvider>(
        builder: (context, shopInfoProvider, enrolledProductSessionProvider,
            registeredProductSessionProvider, Widget child) {
      if (widget.isNavRegistered) {
        sessionList = registeredProductSessionProvider
            .registeredProductSessionList.data;
      } else {
        sessionList =
            enrolledProductSessionProvider.enrolledProductSessionList.data;
      }
      sessionList.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

      //added future builder to wait for the session status update
      return FutureBuilder<List<Session>>(
        future: WidgetUtils.checkAndUpdateSessionStatus(sessionList,
            productSessionProvider, shopInfoProvider.shopInfo.data),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Session>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting &&!snapshot.hasError) {
            sessionList = snapshot.data; //consolidated sessionList

            if (sessionList.length > 0) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: PsExpansionTile(
                  initiallyExpanded: false,
                  title: _expansionTileTitleWidget,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: PsDimens.space10,
                          left: PsDimens.space10,
                          right: PsDimens.space10),
                      child: sessionList.length > 0
                          ? Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Center(
                                    child: _buildSessionDataTable(context)),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(child: Text('None')),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      );
    }));
```

As noted above, I have MultiProvider with few consumers. Within the Consumer3 code block, I have FutureBuilder as I have async session status update method checkAndUpdateSessionStatus(). The consumer3 code block is triggered multiple times and I think it is the nature of the MultiProvider Consumer model. Problem is that right now checkAndUpdateSessionStatus() also called multiple times, and I want that to be called once. I can possibly use StreamBuilder and I still need to have async checkAndUpdateSessionStatus().

I am fairly new to flutter. I have seen many StackOverFow items on how to prevent multi build stuff and none of them address my core issue (I need MultiProvider but do not want to trigger consumers multiple times and within the consumer, I have an async process, which should not process with multiple consumer triggers).

Any solution or an alternate solution would really help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. You can try `Selector` (which I tried once, but I knew what I was doing less than I do now, so will be trying it again). Also, `Provider` has had [some pretty cool updates from v4.1.0 on](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/changelog). For instance, v4.2.0 added a builder parameter on MultiProvider. I'm going to look into this as well. Here's [a post with some explanations and examples](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/using-context-extensions-for-more-control).